# OSCommerce USPS convert weight unit from Pound to Ounces

Tags: php, data-conversion, units-of-measurement, oscommerce, usps

I am working on an OSCommerce site, and for the USPS Shipping method I want to convert the weight unit from Pounds to Ounces, but not getting the way how.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried Googling `OSCommerce USPS convert weight unit from Pound to Ounces`? There seem to be helpful resources out there

Comment: Yes I did a lot, but didn't found anything useful... :(

Comment: Looks like this contrib is supporting ounces http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,487

Answer (score 4):

Given that 1 pound = 16 ounces, you can basically just multiply it by 16:

```
$pounds = 8;
$ounces = $pounds * 16;
echo $ounces; // 128
```

...but, if pounds is a float, you will probably want to round it. Since you are talking about shipping weights, you probably want to round up:

```
$pounds = 8.536;
$ounces = ceil($pounds * 16);
echo $ounces; // 137
```

You could put this into a function, like this:

```
function pounds_to_ounces ($pounds) {
  return ceil($pounds * 16);
}

echo pounds_to_ounces(8); // 128
echo pounds_to_ounces(8.536); // 137
```

Comment: that's great, thank you so much... it worked... still I have one more problem.. now how could I set rate from USPS?

Comment: You need to use the USPS rating apis. https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm or http://www.marksanborn.net/php/calculating-usps-shipping-rates-with-php/